# Donot know how to find the Address of DllMain?

Tags: malware, malware-detection

I'm newbie in analyzing Malware. I've installed IDA pro to analyze an malware by name LAb-5 01.dll
As soon as i entered i've loaded the .dll file .But i donot know how to find the address of dllMain.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to locate DLLMain using IDA Pro.

Once you open the DLL you are pointed directly to DLLMain. To know the address you can go to "Options" --> "General" and check "Line Prefixes". This will show that DllMain function is located at 0x1000D02E:

[image: DLLMain Address in graph mode]

There are other ways to find it using IDA Pro. You can also search the symbol using the option "Search" --> "text" and writing "DllMain". It might not land in the function definition but you can double-click the symbol to go to the definition.

Another option is going to the Function Window at "Windows" --> "Functions window" (or Alt+1) and scroll until you find DllMain.

[image: Functions window]